# Stop audio on click and replay

Tags: javascript, audio

```
<button class="button" style="width: 200px;" onclick="playSound()">Play sound</button>

function playSound() {
          audio.pause();
          var audio = new Audio('V2018-Museum-filer/mp3file.mp3');
          audio.play();
        }
```

When clicking the button multiple tiems to start the audio multiple times, i want to stop the audio already playing for it to replay. How can i do this? I get an error saying audio is undefined.

Comment: Because you access `audio` before you "create" it. Place `var audio = ...` before `function playSound()`. Also, to stop your currently playing audio, I suggest adding `audio.currentTime = 0;` right after `audio.pause();`.

Comment: Happy to help :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps...

When the button is clicked, the audio is paused and restarts on second click.

```js
function playSound() {
  var audioControl = document.getElementById('sound');
  var btn = $("#player");

  if (btn.click && audioControl.paused !== true) {
    audioControl.pause();
  } else if (btn.click && audioControl.paused === true) {
  audioControl.currentTime = 0;
    audioControl.play();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="sound" controls>
  <source src="http://www.largesound.com/ashborytour/sound/brobob.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<button id="player" style="width: 200px;" onclick="playSound()">Play sound</button>
```